Question for analytic variety (in Griffiths and Harris)
I'm reading "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" of Griffiths and Harris. This is the content of the book(page 13):

My question is how can we deduce that $r$ vanish identically on $\pi^{-1}(z)$ from $deg(r)<deg(g)$. I think it is true when $g$ is irreducible. However, this paragraph does not contain this assumption.
